# Array search value find multiples keys

Tags: arrays, search

i have an array like this

```
$example = array("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d", "c");
```

i want like this write in page.

```
echo example (a b c d)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.unique(array.sort());
```

This will give you a sorted array `(a,b,c,d)`, then you can write in your page any way.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var example = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d", "c"]; 
     var a=[];var u={};
        for(var i = 0; i< example.length; i ++){
              if(u.hasOwnProperty(example[i])) {
                 continue;
              }
              a.push(example[i]);
              u[example[i]] = 1;
           }

//variable a will contain the unique value use this variable wherever you want
```